# dynamic name property for php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use this code for generating dynamic name attribute in my HTML page based on index key for each input tag that user add with a plus button:

```
var afterRemove = function afterRemove() {
    var setIndex = function setIndex(inputNamePrefix) {
        $('input[name^="' + inputNamePrefix + '"]').each(function (index, value) {
            $(this).attr('name', '' + inputNamePrefix + index);
        });
    };
    ['jobTitle', 'organName', 'jobYearFrom', 'jobYearTo'].forEach(function (prefix) {
        setIndex(prefix);
    });
    ['research', 'researchComment'].forEach(function (prefix) {
        setIndex(prefix);
    });
    ['teachingsub', 'teachingpr', 'teachingplace'].forEach(function (prefix) {
        setIndex(prefix);
    });
    ['teacherMobile', 'teacherTel', 'teacherEmail'].forEach(function (prefix) {
        setIndex(prefix);
    });
    ['fieldofstudy', 'univercity', 'eduYearFrom', 'eduYearTo', 'eduPaper'].forEach(function (prefix) {
        setIndex(prefix);
    });

};
```

Now I need to get each name attribute dynamically in PHP. For example, user may have 3 `phoneNumber: {teacherMobile0,teacherMobile1,teacherMobile2}`. For each theme I need a variable in PHP. How can I know how many name has been generated by user?

Comment: You dont need to. If you gave each occurance a unique name then these unique names will appear in the $_POST or $_GET arrays. Thats not the best way to do it but thats another question

Comment: `count()` can count it. I hope you know what you're doing.

Comment: You would be better making each HTML input field an array i.e. `name="fieldofstudy[]"` and `name="univercity[]"` Then they arrive to PHP as arrays as well. **You would not need to do any of this fudging with names then**

Comment: because i do not know how many fields will be generated by user, i need to name that fields dynamically.

Comment: **No you dont** use array naming like I suggest above

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you explain more specific?

Comment: What if I make a post through, say curl, your logic will likely fail.

Comment: @Chay22 This looks like javascript so cURL is hardly relevant

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was pretending to be an attacker that also turned javascript off :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I assume you have a table of inputs and you let the user add rows to that table with a click on a button which runs a bit of javascript to add a new row

If you name the fields as

```
<td><input name="fieldofstudy[]" .....></td>
<td><input name="univercity[]" .....></td>
etc etc
```

You no longer have to worry about adding prefix or suffix counts to these input.

Then all you need to do to create a new row in javascript is [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the last row in the table, blank the `.val()` of each cell and a new row is ready to go

Then in PHP you will receive an array for each variable i.e.

```
$_POST['fieldofstudy'][]
$_POST['univercity'][]
```

Which you can process as

```
foreach ( $_POST['fieldofstudy'] as $idx => $fieldofstudy) {
    echo $fieldofstudy;
    echo $_POST['univercity'][$idx];
}
```